# Cut part of video with gstreamer pipeline

Tags: c++, gstreamer

For example I have mp4 videofile with 60 sec duration, how to cut part of video from 10 to 20 sec? Is it passible to use gst-launch for that? Or it can be done only with using gst_element_seek? Also if we use seeking, then how to stop recording after 10 sec of video written?

Thank!